# Detect groups of numbers in a list?

Tags: python, list, grouping

I'm looking for a way to group numbers from a list while looping over them if the they fall into a range.

for instance here is a list of numbers:

```
days = [18, 19, 26, 9, 15, 16, 22, 2, 9, 15, 16, 23, 28, 30, 6, 13, 19, 20, 25,27,
        4, 11, 17, 18, 25, 1, 8, 14, 15, 22, 27, 29, 6, 13, 19, 20, 26, 27,
        3, 10, 16, 17, 24, 25, 31, 7, 14, 20, 21, 26, 28, 5, 12, 18, 19, 26,
        2, 9, 15, 16, 23, 27, 30, 7, 14, 20, 21, 28]
```

While looping over the list I want to group them into a list of tuples if the number is greater that 1 and less than 32 e.g.`[(18, 19, 26), (9, 15, 16, 22)]` etc...). Does anyone have a reasonable way to do this?

I have tried using recipes from the itertools library but have failed.

example:

```
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(days), lambda (i,x):x in date_range):
    print map(itemgetter(1), g)
```

this example will generate lists of consecutive numbers. I appreciate any help.

Comment: What determines the length of each tuple? In your example, it seems random...

Comment: *e.g.[(18, 19, 26), (9, 15, 16, 22)] etc..* I'm not able to work out what *etc* would be.

Comment: Are you splitting when two values are not incremental?

Comment: what determines the the length is whether the number falls in the range(1, 32) so I basically need to create a tuple of numbers while iterating.

Comment: All of those numbers are in that range. It looks like you want to start a new group when a number is smaller than the previous one.

Comment: Each one of the tuples in my question has numbers that fall between 1 and 32. I'm simply trying to create tuples from the numbers in the "days" list with those numbers.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 that is correct

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) I bet he wants these split up into months (1-31)(1-31)(etc...)

Comment: I need also need to put those tuples in a list.

Comment: Then that was a critical part of your question. Otherwise, this is valid: `days = (18, 19, 26, 9, 15, 16, 22, 2, 9, 15, 16, 23, 28, 30, 6, 13, 19, 20, 25,27,
        4, 11, 17, 18, 25, 1, 8, 14, 15, 22, 27, 29, 6, 13, 19, 20, 26, 27,
        3, 10, 16, 17, 24, 25, 31, 7, 14, 20, 21, 26, 28, 5, 12, 18, 19, 26,
        2, 9, 15, 16, 23, 27, 30, 7, 14, 20, 21, 28)`

Comment: @TemporalWolf you are also correct should have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: So, much for the idea that the dupe was unlikely to help future visitors!

Answer (score -1):

```
last_day = 0
sublist = []
result = []
for day in days:
    if day > last_day:
        sublist.append(day)
    else:
        result.append(tuple(sublist))
        sublist = [day]
    last_day = day
result.append(tuple(sublist))  # append the final list
```

Goes through them and builds sublists, which are then converted to tuples and added to the result list.

The result is:

```
[(18, 19, 26), (9, 15, 16, 22), (2, 9, 15, 16, 23, 28, 30), 
 (6, 13, 19, 20, 25, 27), (4, 11, 17, 18, 25), (1, 8, 14, 15, 22, 27, 29), 
 (6, 13, 19, 20, 26, 27), (3, 10, 16, 17, 24, 25, 31), 
 (7, 14, 20, 21, 26, 28), (5, 12, 18, 19, 26), 
 (2, 9, 15, 16, 23, 27, 30), (7, 14, 20, 21, 28)]
```

Comment: Apart from this question already having an answer in the linked duplicate, this particular solution will fail if the last group has a single element.

Comment: Thanks TemporWolf,  this is the correct answer, forgive if the question wasn't clear enough but my e.g[(18, 19, 26)] etc..) should have been a big enough clue.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Fair enough, but that can be fixed and it's significantly less complicated than all of the posted answers to the dupe'd question. At the very least the dupe'd question should be opened if it's going to be the authoritative source.

Comment: If a question is closed as being off-topic for the site, that means it isn't suitable for the site and shouldn't be answered.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The dupe'd question was closed as being *unlikely to help any future visitors*, which it being dupe'd seems to contradict. Also, I've fixed the code: it was dropping the last tuple regardless of length.